# Angular animation - improving basecode

Tags: angular, css-animations

Hey I have a following animation. The goal is here to have it kid of bounce effect, so that the element becomes enlarged and then back to its original size. My question is , is there a way to improve this code? It works but I have to change the state manually and calculate the delay and so on....

```
animations: [
    trigger('balloonEffect', [
      state('initial', style({
        transform: 'scale(1)'
      })),
      state('final', style({
        transform: 'scale(1.4)'
      })),
      transition('final=>initial', animate('300ms')),
      transition('initial=>final', animate('300ms'))
    ]),
  ]

currentState = 'initial';

  changeState() {
    this.currentState = 'final';
    setTimeout(() => this.currentState = 'initial', 300)
  }

  <button [disabled]="isFormSelectionCompleted()"
                *ngIf="hasNoForms()"
                (click)="changeState()"
                [@balloonEffect]=currentState
                mat-raised-button color="primary"
                #addButton>Stwórz</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `keyframes` if you don't want to manage the animation duration and state with `setTimeout`. I think it is bit cleaner:

```js
function balloonEffect() {
  return trigger('balloonEffect', [
    transition('true <=> false', [
      animate('500ms', keyframes( [
        style({ transform: 'scale(1)' }),
        style({ transform: 'scale(1.5)' }),
        style({ transform: 'scale(1)' })
      ]))
    ])
  ]);
}
```

```html
<button [@balloonEffect]="triggerBalloon" (click)="showDetails()">
  Show details
</button>
```

And in the component:

```js
@Component({
  ...
  animations: [balloonEffect()]
})
export class MyComponent {

  constructor() {}

  triggerBalloon = false;

  showDetails() {
    this.triggerBalloon=!this.triggerBalloon;
    console.log('Do stuff');
  }
}
```

We could also trigger the effect in the template itself and remove it from the components `showDetails` method:

```html
<button [@balloonEffect]="triggerBalloon" 
        (click)="triggerBalloon=!triggerBalloon;showDetails()">
  Show details
</button>
```

Here's the [blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/animations-button-bounce-no-state?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstepper-overview-example.html)